# How do I get an array name out of a javascript array? Possibly a syntax issue - Noob

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, settimeout

I am creating a program in a which a video plays of a person speaking and chunks of the text appear in a div as the words are spoken with a translation.  I am trying to write a javascript function to make that happen.  Basically,  I am changing the visibility of the div's with "setTimeout" so the text is revealed at the right time.

I have these 3 arrays

```
var invite =["itimes", "idivs"];  //names of 2 arrays which contain the info for the "invite" text block
var itimes =["0", "642", "950", "2555", "1113"]; //times in msec when text should be revealed 
var idivs = ["speech_bubble", "i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"]; //divs to be revealed
```

These are the 2 functions I have written to cause the text to be revealed

```
function reveal(){                    //change visibility of div name retrieved
        var textchunk = "invite"
        var divs =  textchunk[1];       
            var div = {Value: divs[x]};           //x value comes from timedreveal div
            var divtoreveal = document.getElementById(div);
            divtoreveal.style.visibility = 'visible';   
}

function timedreveal() {
        var textchunk = "invite"       //the textchunk value will later be set by another function but 
                                       //here I just set it to invite so I could try to get it working
        var times = textchunk[0];

        for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++)
        {
            var wait = {Value: times[x]};
            alert(JSON.stringify(wait, null, 4));
            setTimeout(reveal, wait);
        }
}
```

timedreveal retrieves 'itimes' just fine from the 'invite' array but then when I alert its length I get the length of the word 'itimes' and not the length of the 'itimes' array.  The first value it retrieves is "i" not "0". It is not treating 'itimes' as the name of the array but as as the values of an array named 'times' with 6 elements.  I have tried to look this up and read a bunch of posts but haven't understood how to fix it.  One suggested I put all three arrays inside a sort of superarray but I don't understand how to access the data in that case.  Any advice would be great.

Thanks, Kate

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a string instead of array.

```
var textchunk = "invite"
```

should be

```
var textchunk = invite;
```

In your case

```
> var textchunk = "invite"
> var divs =  textchunk[1];
```

textchunk will a string "invite" and techchunk[1] will return the letter at position 1, so divs will have value **n**

Comment: While correctly pointing out the first issue, this will not fully solve her problem. invite array contains other variable names. Later on OP is trying reference a variable by string which is not really possible, without a lot of ugly work.

Comment: I tried it initially without "quotes" but it didn't work that way either.  Sinanspd, if I eliminate the 'invite' array and just take the time/code to set the 2 variables 'times' and 'divs' can I avoid the ugly work of which you speak??  It sounds like it is not OK to put variable names in an array.

Comment: @KateLeVering It is ok, as long as you put the name, not a string literal whose value is the name (See Rahul's answer). There is a big difference between a string and a variable name. There is absolutely no need to do that, ever, even if you are doing runtime reflection, because variable names are referential values in the first place. They get scraped away by the language anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var itimes =["0", "642", "950", "2555", "1113"]; //times in msec when text should be revealed 
var idivs = ["speech_bubble", "i1", "i2", "i3", "i4"]; //divs to be revealed
var invite =[itimes,idivs];
var times = invite[0]; // in timedreveal()
var divs =  invite[1]; // in reveal()
```

can you try like this, because you're pushing strings in array not array themselves.

Comment: OK I commented out the top 2 lines from each function so we aren't dealing with textchunk anymore and I replaced my arrays with yours plus the definition of times and divs.  Now the "timedreveal" function is reading each of the times out of itimes correctly based on the alert.  I am still not getting anything revealed on the screen so I will go troubleshoot a bit more.